# Swift change String with range & and shouldChangeTextInRange how to know backspace

Tags: swift, textview, swift2, mention

I am New in Swift , and i lot of RND but i cant able to get success. i have Replace string with range i am using this Code But its return error i am using swift 2.0

```
let aString: String = txt_description.text
        let newString = aString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(varattherate, withString:"@\(getText) ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: NSMakeRange(0, 10))
```

Acutely The problem is , i have replace text from string 
my String is **"my name is @test but i want change @te"** and replace 
**"@te"** replace with **"@test"** but i have changes on last "@te" of String , I am try to create "Autocomplete Text View "

But i am using this code

```
 let aString: String = "my name is @test but i want change @te"
 let newString = aString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(varattherate, withString:"@\(getText) ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range:nil)
```

and the output is "my name is @testst but i want change @test"
but i have Need Output "my name is @test but i want change @test" Not change first @te  only last one is change with dynamic

**Second Problem  is** 
How to know in this function backspace

```
 func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool 
{


}
```

I am try this code but is not working 
text: String) -> Bool {

```
    if(text == "\b") {
        println("This is backspace ")
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this example to understand your second question

```
// this is ASCII BS (backspace)
let cBS: Int8 = 0x08
let asciitxt: [Int8] = [65,66,67,cBS,68,0]
let asString = String.fromCString(asciitxt)
print(asciitxt)
print(asString)
print(asString!)

/*
[65, 66, 67, 8, 68, 0]
Optional("ABC\u{08}D")
ABCD
*/
```

the answer to your first question is just about the logic in your parsing code ... it is not very swift specific at all